# Is "massive" usage of #region considered a bad practice?

Tags: c#, region

My `MainViewModel` has to deal with a lot of commands with complex actions inside, therefore its extension has grown inevitable. For keep the code organized I tend to use `#region` to group similar o related tasks.Does this considered an overuse of this feature or it's perfectly normal? You may say that it depends on me, if I feel right about it. I think that it helps a lot but I would like to know what do others. Here is a screenshot of how the code look like:

[image]

Comment: If you need that many `#region`s then you have a God Object. And that is worse than having a bunch of `#region`s. Divide that `MainViewModel`!

Comment: Personally, I finds it clutters the code uselessly. Normally you can read the code from top to bottom, like a novel, without problems. The regions in this case only make it hard to read. Also, this means your class does way too many things. When I think about doing a region, I separate this in a different class to follow the SRP principle.

Comment: would love to see those line numbers in the screenshot :)

Comment: I think it was like 1k lines, not too bad.

Answer (score 7):

The bad practice is a massive single class. #region is simply hiding / coping with it.
If there are groups of methods, delegate them to another class.